# Don't process element if id has no value or duplicated, using XSLT-2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LearningStandards>
  <CoreStandardVersion>1.3</CoreStandardVersion>
  <LearningStandardItem xml:lang="en" RefID="B7058B531113">
    <RefURI>http://ramstand.org/KBL-ELvier/DDSS/L/1/</RefURI>
  </LearningStandardItem>
  <LearningStandardItem xml:lang="en" RefID="E2D9EF8B042C091">
    <RefURI>http://ramstand.org/KBL-ELvier/DDSS/L/2/</RefURI>
  </LearningStandardItem>
    <LearningStandardItem xml:lang="en" RefID="B7058B531113">
    <RefURI>http://ramstand.org/KBL-ELvier/DDSS/L/1/</RefURI>
  </LearningStandardItem>
    </LearningStandardItem>
    <LearningStandardItem xml:lang="en">
    <RefURI>http://ramstand.org/KBL-ELvier/DDSS/L/3/</RefURI>
  </LearningStandardItem>
</LearningStandards>
```

**Transformation XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LearningStandards">
        <topic id="x1" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="KKSSS-DITA">
            <title>KKSSS</title>
            <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </topic>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CoreStandardVersion"/>

    <xsl:template match="LearningStandardItem">        
                <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </bodydiv>        
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="LearningStandardItem/@xml:lang"/>

    <xsl:template match="@RefID">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@RefID">
        <xsl:if test=". != ''">
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic id="x1" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="KKSS-DITA">
   <title>KKSSS</title>
   <body>

      <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem"
               id="B7058B531113">
         <p outputclass="RefURI">http://ramstand.org/KBL-ELvier/DDSS/L/1/</p>
      </bodydiv>
      <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem"
               id="E2D9EF8B042C091">
         <p outputclass="RefURI">http://ramstand.org/KBL-ELvier/DDSS/L/2/</p>
      </bodydiv>
      <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem"
               id="B7058B531113">
         <p outputclass="RefURI">http://ramstand.org/KBL-ELvier/DDSS/L/1/</p>
      </bodydiv>
      <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem">
         <p outputclass="RefURI">http://ramstand.org/KBL-ELvier/DDSS/L/3/</p>
      </bodydiv>  
    </body>
</topic>
```

Output needed as following conditions:

1) if **ID** has no value, then do not process the element.
2) if **ID** is a duplicate of a previous `<LearningStandardItem>` element, then do not process the element.
3) Otherwise process `<LearningStandardItem>`

**Expected output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic id="x1" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="KKSSS-DITA">
   <title>KKSSS</title>
   <body>

      <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem"
               id="B7058B531113">
         <p outputclass="RefURI">http://ramstand.org/KBL-ELvier/DDSS/L/1/</p>
      </bodydiv>
      <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem"
               id="E2D9EF8B042C091">
         <p outputclass="RefURI">http://ramstand.org/KBL-ELvier/DDSS/L/2/</p>
      </bodydiv>
     </body>
</topic>
```

Please assist me.

Comment: I faced a similar issue, this is tricky to solve with xslt 1 but not impossible, with xslt 2 it's more straight forward, which version are you using?

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0 and Saxon-PE 9.6.0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a template as below to skip the `LearningStandardItem` elements with no `@RefID` or null value `@RefID` or a duplicate `@RefID`:

```
<xsl:template match="LearningStandardItem[not(@RefID[.!='']) or preceding-sibling::LearningStandardItem[@RefID = current()/@RefID]]"/>
```

Comment: Be aware though this this solution is inefficient (specifically it is O(n^2) in the number of `LearningStandardItem` siblings). A more scalable solution would be to define a key `K` that indexes `LearningStandardItem` elements on their `@RefID` attribute, and then exclude those where the predicate `not(@RefID = key('K', @RefID)[1])` is true.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Dr. Kay, would the predicate you mentioned work when the key `K` is actually indexing `LearningStandardItem`? I was thinking a predicate something like `not(. is key('K', @RefID)[1])` would do.